# Linux "make" command Error 127

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, makefile

I'm new to Linux and trying to install [mktorrent](http://mktorrent.sourceforge.net/) (latest version) and the README file states to simply run the 'make' command while in the directory. However, after trying 3 different terminals/emulators I would receive the same error as shown quoted below.

I've tried install "automake" from repositories as suggested through other answers found on here/Google with no luck. Here are the directory contents: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlAsg.png

> cc -O2 -Wall   prefix.c -o prefix make: cc: Command not found make:
>   *** [prefix] Error 127

Comment: Looks like the command `cc` does not exist on your system. That would be the c compiler.

Comment: If you have `gcc` but not `cc`, check if it will compile successfully with `gcc`. You can modify Makefile to change `cc` to `gcc`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

should install the requirements for compiling C/C++ based applications